# Dynamically setting `input` type in angularjs - not works

Tags: angularjs, angular-template

I am tying to set the `input` field dynamically. But I came up with `error`. how to use the `ng-switch-when` to set the type in `input` fields or any other alternate?

here is my temp:

```
var GridTemplate = [
            '<div>',
                '<div>',
                    '<ul class="titles"><li  ng-repeat="page in currentPage">{{page.title}}</li></ul>',
                    '<div class="rowContent">',
                    '<ul ng-repeat="(title,page) in currentPage">',
                        '<li  ng-repeat="(key,element) in page.key track by $index">',
                        '<input ng-switch-when="page.key[key] == string" type="text" name="" id="" ng-model="page.key[key]" ng-blur="numSort( page )" />',
                        '<input ng-switch-when="page.key[key] == number" name="" id="" ng-model="page.key[key]" ng-blur="numSort( page )" />',
                        '</li></ul></div>',
                    '<div class="pageNavigator"><ul><li  ng-repeat="page in slides"><a ng-href="">{{$index+1}}</a></li></ul></div>',
                '</div>',
            '</div>'
            ];
```

Comment: What error are you getting

Comment: error is : `Controller 'ngSwitch', required by directive 'ngSwitchWhen', can't be found!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="{{getInputType(page.key[key])}}" ng-model="page.key[key]" />
```

and then a function in your controller to check the param and return the input type

```
 $scope.getInputType = function(param){
     if(angular.isString(param)) return "text";
     if(angular.isNumber(param)) return "number";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-switch-when` directives need to be wrapped in a `ng-switch` directive.

From [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch):

```
<ANY ng-switch="expression">
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue1">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-when="matchValue2">...</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-default>...</ANY>
</ANY>
```

So in your case I think it would be smth like

```
<li ng-switch="page.key[key]" ng-repeat="(key,element) in page.key track by $index">
  <input ng-switch-when="string" type="text" name="" id="" ng-model="page.key[key]" ng-blur="numSort( page )" />
  <input ng-switch-when="number" name="" id="" ng-model="page.key[key]" ng-blur="numSort( page )" />
</li>
```